# Getting blank pages for error messages with UseDeveloperExceptionPage enabled

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm getting blank pages for both when I enter an invalid URL, or when an exception is thrown within my application. I have UseDeveloperExceptionPage() enabled, and I have confirmed that my app environment is in development mode, and that the method is firing. The app works fine, but not having error messages displaying in the browser is frustrating.

My Startup.cs Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseIdentity();
            app.UseMvc(m =>
            m.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                ));

            if(env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            CreateSampleData(app.ApplicationServices).Wait();
        }
```

My project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The order matters - put `UseMvc(..)` after your exception blocks so the exception middleware can catch exceptions that the Mvc middleware throws.

If you take a look at the [source for `DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/97acf259d9b56bfb5bd22dc1f7eccc5872dace4e/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/DeveloperExceptionPage/DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.cs#L92-L95) you can see that it simply calls the next middleware in the pipeline inside a try/catch.

404s however will still show a blank page, as they are not an exception.  To configure something else for those, take a look at [StatusCodeErrorPages](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/StatusCodePage/StatusCodePagesExtensions.cs).

Comment: All the links are dead !

Comment: `app.UseStatusCodePages()` was what I was looking for

Comment: @SerjSagan Thank you, just adding .NET Core 6.0 docs link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0#usestatuscodepages