# Cannot get default error page in Asp.Net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My asp.net 5 application is throwing a blank html page at me, if an exception occurs. My goal is to display the default error page.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902135/asp-net-5-custom-error-page-does-not-render-on-azure-website) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326681/not-hitting-error-page-on-asp-net-5-app) seem to be related, but it is seems to be outdated, since we don't have a web.config any longer and the second one doesnt solve my problem.

This is my `Configure()` method in the startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Warning);

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc(config =>
    {
        //[...]
    });

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseBrowserLink();
        loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Information);
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Debug);
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    //[...]
}
```

I have confirmed, that the code is actually hitting the if condition and the UserDeveloperExceptionPage method is loaded, but to no avail.

What am I missing?

Comment: You may not be using a web.config in your application, but you can still use them, as well as other configuration files.  Take a look at the cloud-ready configuration section in this article:  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5.  Also, take a look at this question, seems related to your issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304575/getting-blank-pages-for-error-messages-with-usedeveloperexceptionpage-enabled

Comment: Yep, this is actually a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a solution

**Order matters.** You need to instantiate the error handling middleware before the MVC middleware. Otherwise, there will be just no exception handling.

Putting the error handling configuration just before the `app.UseMvc(x => {...})` does the trick:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseBrowserLink();
    loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Information);
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseMvc(config =>
{
    //[...]
});
```

Simple as that.